# Unterschied zwischen „um zu“ und „zum“?

Tags: grammar, infinitive

> Ich trinke Alkohol, um zu feiern.

Man kann auch sagen:

> Ich trinke Alkohol zum Feiern.

Kein Komma, ja?

Gibt es Situationen, in denen man *zum* statt *um zu* nicht benutzen kann?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Da ich der Meinung bin, dass man auch ohne Alkohol gut feiern kann, wähle ich ein anderes Beispiel, das aber denselben grammatischen Sachverhalt beinhaltet:

> a) Ich gehe auf den Ball, um zu tanzen.
>   b) Ich gehe zum Tanzen auf den Ball.

### a

Die Phrase »um zu tanzen« in (a) ist eine finale nebensatzwertige Infinitivgruppe. Nebensätze sind immer mit einem Komma abzutrennen. »Final« bedeutet, dass der Nebensatz am Ende des Satzes steht, ihn also abschließt.

Dieser finale Nebensatz gibt einen Zweck oder eine Absicht an. Man kann danach wie folgt fragen:

- Wozu?
- Mit welchem Zweck?
- Mit welcher Absicht?

gebildet wird dieser Nebensatz mit den beiden Worten »**um zu**« und dem Infinitiv eines Verbs:

> Ich lege mich ins Bett, um zu schlafen.
>   Ich gehe in die Fabrik, um zu arbeiten.

Man kann das auch andersherum betrachten: Wenn ein Infinitiv am Ende des Satzes steht, und ihm das Wort »**zu**« unmittelbar vorangestellt ist, oder – im Fall eines trennbaren Verbs – wenn das Wort »**zu**« als Infix ins Verb eingefügt wurde, und wenn davor noch das Wort »**um**« steht, handelt es sich um eine nebensatzwertige Infinitivphrase, die mit einem Komma abzutrennen ist:

> Der Zeuge kam, um aus**zu**sagen.

### b

Die Phrase »zum Tanzen« in (b) enthält ebenfalls einen Infinitiv, davor steht aber das Wort »zum«, das eine Verschmelzung aus der Präposition »zu« und dem bestimmten Artikel »dem« ist. Und dieser Artikel (Dativ, Neutrum), der in »zum« verborgen ist, bewirkt die Substantivierung des nachfolgenden Verbs. Es ist also gar kein Verb mehr, sondern ein Substantiv, und muss als solches in einem deutschen Satz mit großem Anfangsbuchstaben geschrieben werden.

Ein substantivierter Infinitiv ist aber kein Nebensatz, auch nicht wenn man den Artikel und die Präposition hinzurechnet. Und daher ist eine Abtrennung mittels Komma nicht nur nicht erforderlich, sondern wäre sogar falsch.

Auch nach dieser Phrase kann man mit denselben Fragen wie in (a) fragen. Daher kann man sie als semantisch gleichwertig ansehen. Mir fällt kein Beispiel ein, bei dem es zwischen a und b einen Bedeutungsunterschied gäbe.

---

Die deutsche Grammatik ist gegenüber alternativen Wortstellungen sehr tolerant, daher kann der substantivierte Infinitiv samt »**zu**« + Artikel vor oder auch nach dem Objekt stehen. Beide Varianten sind richtig, solange der substantivierte Infinitiv großgeschrieben und nicht mit Kommas vom Rest des Satzes abgetrennt wird. Nach meinem Sprachgefühl klingt aber die Variante, bei der **zum** + substantivierter Infinitiv direkt nach dem Prädikat steht, besser:

> Ich gehe zum Tanzen auf den Ball.
>   Ich gehe auf den Ball zum Tanzen.

Wenn in diesem Beispiel das Wort »tanzen« am Ende des Satzes genannt werden soll, dann würde ich eher zu Variante a (um + zu + Infinitiv) greifen.

Comment: *»Final« bedeutet, dass der Nebensatz am Ende des Satzes steht, ihn also abschließt.* – Nein, _final_ bedeutet in der Grammatik ‘eine Absicht, ein Ziel ausdrückend’. Ein Finalsatz oder eine entsprechende Infinitivgruppe kann problemlos auch am Anfang eines Gefüges stehen: Um das richtigzustellen, habe ich diesen Kommentar geschrieben.

Comment: Wir haben es bestimmt mit zwei verschiedenen Bedeutungen von *final* zu tun – das Finale, also das letzte nach örtlichen/zeitlichen Gesichtspunkten oder aber *final* im grammatikalischen Sinne, also zum Zweck.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast, Da muss man auch erwähnen, dass die Variante B (A aber nicht) auch ein Mittel bedeuten könnte. "Ich verwende den Stift zum Schrieben."