# "zu erschöpft sein zum / um zu / für's"

Tags: preposition, phrase, grammaticality

Gestern hat mich mein Sprachgefühl im Stich gelassen und sowohl der Eintrag im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erschoepft) als auch in [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ersch%C3%B6pft) hat mir nicht weitergeholfen.

Ich möchte sagen, dass ich nicht kochen werde/kochen kann, weil ich zu erschöpft bin.

> 1. Ich bin zu erschöpft, um zu kochen.
> 2. Ich bin zu erschöpft zum Kochen.
> 3. Ich bin zu erschöpft für's Kochen.

Ich dachte zuerst Version 1 wäre richtig, aber war dann irritiert, weil *um zu* ja eigentlich einen Zweck angibt (Vgl. [Unterschied zwischen um zu und zum](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27417/unterschied-zwischen-um-zu-und-zum)). Also, welche Version ist richtig?

Comment: Mein Sprachgefühl würde jetzt spontan version 1 wählen, ich kann das aber nicht Wissenschaftlich begründen. Zudem ist v. 1 ja auch die einzige, die Tatsächlich mit dem Verb gebildet wird. Allerdings würder ich eher sagen:  _Ich bin zu erschöpft, um kochen zu können._

Comment: ... als dass ich kochen könnte ;)

Comment: @Carsten S, daran hatte ich bisher gar nicht gedacht. Das ist gut!

Comment: Wenn Du Dich besonders gestelzt ausdrücken möchtest ;). Ansonsten ist 1auf jeden Fall geläufig: https://youtu.be/HkVPQSluUAM

Comment: Ich habe an keiner der drei Versionen etwas auszusetzen. Lediglich »für's« müsste durch »fürs« ersetzt werden: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fuers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Meiner Meinung nach ist Version 1 die beste und richtige Variante. [Laut Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/um_damit)

> leitet [um] (manchmal weglassbar) einen konsekutiven Infinitiv oder Infinitivsatz ein

Bei "Ich bin zu erschöpft, um zu kochen." handelt es sich auch deutlich um einen konsekutiven Infinitiv: Die Folge der Erschöpfung ist die Unfähigkeit zu kochen.

Außerdem führt Duden folgenden Beispielsatz zur oben genannten Bedeutung an:

> er ist zu krank, um zu verreisen (als dass er verreisen könnte, wollte, dürfte)

Dieser Satz ist wohl unbestreitbar mit dem Satz aus Version 1 vergleichbar.

Version 2 und 3 sind zwar verständlich, klingen aber für mich nicht standardsprachlich. Ich kann auch zu "für" in Duden keine Bedeutung finden, die konsekutiv wäre und "zum" klingt für mich hier einfach nur falsch, schließlich ist es die Kurzform für "zu dem", was hier wirklich nicht passt.

Comment: Ich habe 2 Jahre in Vorarlberg, Österreich gewohnt, und dort hört man viel häufiger "... zum Kochen" als ".. um zu kochen". Ich würde nicht sofort sagen, dass es "falsch" ist!

Comment: @Ed_4434 Vorneweg: Ich bin gebürtiger Vorarlberger. "Zum" ist einfach das Vorarlberger Dialekt Wort zu "zu" und wird deshalb sehr häufig verwendet. Trotzdem interessant, dass das "um" einfach verschwindet. Aber nur weil man etwas in Vorarlberg sagt, würde ich wirklich noch lange nicht sagen, dass es nicht "falsch" ist.

Answer (score -4):

Also, schauen wir uns das mal an:

### Version 1…

… ist ein so genannter „[um-zu-Satz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Um-zu-Satz)“. Er sollte sich 1:1 in einen [Finalsatz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finalsatz) übersetzen lassen. Das wäre dann: „Ich bin zu erschöpft, damit ich koche.“ Wie du siehst, macht das absolut keinen Sinn.

Diese Version ist demnach **falsch**, wird aber umgangssprachlich verstanden.

### Version 2 und 3…

…sind die grammatikalisch korrekten Versionen und sprachlich identisch. Beide Sätze benutzen ein [Präpositionalobjekt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objekt_(Grammatik)#Pr.C3.A4positionalobjekt). Welche Präposition verwendet wird, ist egal - du hast aber selber festgestellt, dass du alternativ auch zu einem Finalsatz neigen würdest, weshalb die Präposition „zu“ natürlicher zu sein scheint.

Version 3 ist indes in anderer Hinsicht falsch, denn das Apostroph kommt im Deutschen nur als Auslassungszeichen von Teilen eines Wortes vor (z.B. „einen“ → „'nen“), nicht bei zusammengezogenen Wörtern.

Comment: "für's" ist kein Genitiv-s, sondern da wurde das "das" ausgelassen. Daher finde ich das Apostroph da völlig richtig.

Comment: "um zu kochen" ist kein um-zu-Satz nach der Wikipedia-Definition: um zu kochen ist nicht das Ziel, sondern die bereits erfüllte Bedingung. "Das Wasser ist zu kalt, um darin zu schwimmen", "Er ist nicht alt genug, um Bier zu trinken." In all diesen Fällen klappt der Umbau mit "damit" nicht, aber die Sätze sind meiner Meinung nach trotzdem korrekt.

Comment: @Robert, mit dem Apostroph hat Dominik völlig recht. http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fuers

Comment: @CarstenS Hm, guter Einwand! Ich hätte da ein Apostroph erlaubt. http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/apostroph scheint nicht völlig abgeneigt, aber ohne sieht es besser aus. Danke!

Comment: @Robert Ja, dass das deiner Meinung nach richtig ist, mag sein. Die Frage war aber, was grammatikalisch korrekt ist, und da kennt die deutsche Hochsprache um-zu-Sätze nun einmal nur als Finalsatz. Wenn du dieser Auslegung widersprechen möchtest, dann bringe doch bitte eine Quelle an, die die Konstruktion mit um zu in deinen Beispielsätzen erlaubt.

Comment: @Robert, in dem von dir verlinkten Artikel steht "Regel 14: 1. Bei den allgemein üblichen Verschmelzungen von Präposition (Verhältniswort) und Artikel setzt man in der Regel keinen Apostroph." als Beispiel ist "fürs" genannt. Am falschen Apostroph besteht für mich kein Zweifel mehr (auch wenn der Hinweis auf das Genetiv-s in der Antwort unpassend ist).